# onClick does not work when I load image from database ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am making a user profile page with an image avatar.
The code works perfectly until the user re-enters the profile page; in that case, nothing happens when the user clicks on the profile image.
It should remove the image on the first click, and then he should be able to upload a different image.
I store the image as a base64 string.

Code I use to set preview image:

```
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=> {
        if(image){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                setPreview(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        }else{
            setPreview(null);
        }
    }, [image]);
```

Code I use to set preview form DB if it exists:

```
                if(userData[11] != ''){
                    setImage(null);
                    setPreview(userData[11]);
                }
```

And finally, in return of component:

```
        {preview ? (<img class="image-preview" onClick={() => {setImage(null)}} src={preview} />) :(
            <div class="image-upload">
                <label for="file-input">
                    <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/bokehlicia/captiva/128/multimedia-photo-manager-icon.png"/>
                </label>
                <input accept="image/*" onChange ={(e) =>{
                    const file = e.target.files[0];
                    if(file && file.type.substring(0, 5) === "image"){
                        setImage(file);
                    } else{setImage(null);}
                    }} id="file-input" type="file" />
            </div>)}
```

onClick event in  tag causes me trouble.

Comment: you're missing a return, or just take out brackets: `{() => setImage(null)}`

Comment: Thanks for helping! Unfortunately, problem is still there after I remove { } or put return before setImage